# My windows 8.1 shows only C:

Tags: windows, windows-8, hard-drive, windows-8.1, partitioning

I have recently installed Windows 8.1, I was previously running 8.0. I had to convert to GPT while installing and had to format my disk. While installing I have created 6 partitions of which I can only see one. The other five are not visible but when I run `list diskpart` it shows all 6 partitions.

Why can't I see my other partitions in Explorer?

Comment: Those partitions might not have letters assigned to them. Check in Windows Disk Management. You can access it by pressing The “windows” key on the keyboard and the “R” key simultaneously. In the Run box that will appear type diskmgmt.msc and press enter. Post a screenshot if you need more help.

Answer (score 3):

Go to Computer Management (right-click on the Start button and click Computer Management).  Under the Storage node in the tree, select Disk Management.  From there you can see the various partitions, create volumes, and assign drive letters to them in the bottom, center pane.